# How memcpy finds the first byte of the passed object?

Tags: c, pointers

Let g be a object designator.

```
void *p = &g;
char *pf =  (char *)p;
```

1. Every pointer type can be converted to a pointer to void and back, the result shall compare equal to original pointer.
2. When a pointer to object type casted to a pointer to character type, the resulting pointer points to the first byte of the object.
3. Pointer to void and pointer to char types are interchangeable.

But at code example above. A void pointer doesn't need to point anything, all it needs to do is to conform condition number 1. So we can't even say that it points to our object. So if we cast that void pointer to  a character pointer we can't say that resulting pointer points to lowest addressing byte of our object.

My question is, if my conclusion is true, how memcpy function finds the lowest addressed byte of the passed object; since every pointer passed to memcpy converted to a pointer to void?

Comment: The pointer you get with the address-of operator `&` will never point to the middle of the object, it will always be a pointer to the first "byte" (whatever that means on the target platform) of the object. Anything else would just not make sense.

Comment: & operator gives a pointer to a object with type of pointer to object. It has nothing to do with bytes as far as i know.

Comment: But the object must be represented some way in memory, and the pointer must point to that memory. It seems you're kind of mixing in the type "pointer to type" with "pointer to object in memory". Those are really two different things, but both can be gotten from the address-of operator.

Comment: You are right. But what i am after is something different. I'm trying to understand how C treats pointers as a language, without any implementation related thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard fails to present rules for pointer conversions expressed in formal mathematics or logic. It expresses rules in natural language (English) in clause 6.3.2.3 (in C 2018). While these natural language rules do not explicitly state that a pointer to an object converted first to `void *` and then to `char *` yields the same result as converting directly to `char *`, this is understood. That is, experienced practitioners with C and compilers understand this is the intent.

Comment: @ErayXx: The C standard does not define conversions between pointers to object types and pointers to function types. If you want to convert a function pointer to an `unsigned char *` and use it to examine the machine code in the function as a learning exercise, then go ahead. If you have notions about using it to change the function, that is not going to work, for a number of reasons. (Properly changing the code inside an executing program requires multiple steps.) In some C implementations, a function pointer does not point to the function’s code but to associated data used for calling it.

Comment: What would be the result of converting a pointer to function first to void * and then to char *. Is this a appropriate thing to do?

Comment: @ErayXx: `void` is an object type. (It is an incomplete type that cannot be completed.) Converting a pointer to a function to `void *` is a conversion between a pointer to a function type and a pointer to an object type. The C standard does not define such conversions. In C implementations where function pointers are implemented as the addresses of function entry points, converting a function pointer to `void *` and then to `char *` will commonly yield the address of the first byte of machine code at the entry point.

Comment: I don't see it on the standard but some say that void isn't a object type. That was bothering me. Thank you for clarifying it.

Comment: @ErayXx: People who say that are wrong. C 2018 6.2.5 19 says “The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.”